# Heap size keep increasing until application crash (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I would like to consult this problem

I have a program that I'm running that in the long run, its memory keep increasing up until all resource are exhausted and of course it crashes (takes several of days to reach critical size).

what I've done till now, is using Valgrind, found all the memory leaks and fixed them, but now I still have a small memory leak that is caused by heap increasing size, for this I used Valgrind massif tool.

the problem is that when I use massif, it cannot run for too long time, and it causes the application to crash after several hours.
I've tried to find the memory leak for an one hour run, the problem that the minimum threshold cannot be lowered from 1% of memory, and after 1 hour I can see memory increase but it still small compare to the rest of the application.
so I can see part that takes more memory, but I cannot see which parts

```
example in valgrind output file:
->03.11% (4,377,152B) in 28 places, all below massif's threshold (01.00%)
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [google perftools](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/).
You can link your program or even LD_PRELOAD the library in and it will profile your heap use generating snapshots, it won't take much of your performance out, when you see that the heap is already too big you can stop it and get a graph of where the memory is spent.

EDIT:
[tutorial here](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/heap_profiler.html)

Example:
[image]

Comment: thought of it, and this exactly why I've posted this here.

because as far as I know, perf tools test performance, and not memory usage, do you know for sure that google perf tool can find memory leaks, and even more important heap increasing issues?

Comment: Yes, perftools and tcmalloc do heap profiling and will provide you with a nice graph of where you are spending the memory, I have used it countless times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used valgrind with -leak-check--full? What are you using that could use memory? Have you deleted every new?

Maybe you crashed because you are allocating a huge memory space at once (happened to me before) and valgrind can't see it sometime.

It is "strange" anyway, tell us the answer if you find it !

Comment: thanks for the response, well the "new" without "delete" valgrind memcheck tool should have found it, so this is not a "memory without pointer" problem.

Comment: this is more of a list that always increase in size "memory leak"